# Css - calculating gray colors

Tags: css, math

How to divide the `#000000` - `#ffffff` interval intro *x* equal parts, to get *x* gray colors? Is this possible?

Edit:
More specifically:
I want 'divide' the `#000000` - `#ffffff` color range like this:

1. #000000
2. #1E1E1E
3. #282828
4. #515151
5. #5B5B5B
6. #848484
7. #8E8E8E
8. #B7B7B7
9. #C1C1C1
10. #EAEAEA
11. #F4F4F4
12. #FFFFFF

In this list there are 12 colors. (Check out the sgi gray colors [here](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm).)

But what if I want not 12 but 32 colors? How to calculate them?
I hope now you understand me :)

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean, sounds interesting tho :) What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#000000 is actually RGB with R = #00, G = #00, B = #00

You get a gray color for R = G = B.

#00 - #FF leaves you with 256 possible combinations, so if you wanna exclude white and black (#000000 and #FFFFFF) try something like this:

```
step = 256 / (x + 2)
```

So if you want to get 4 grays, step resolves to

```
step = 256 / (4+2) = 256 / 6 = 43
```

Transform that from decimal to hex:

```
step_16 = 43_16 = #2B
```

The colors would now be:

```
#2B2B2B
#565656
#818181
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, just divide 255 by `x` and then you will get the step.

Generator in Ruby:

```
def gray_generator(steps)
  step = 255/steps
  ret = []
  steps.times { |i| ret << (step*i).to_s(16) * 3 }
  return ret
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to divide 255(DEC) in x parts. Then, you pass those numbers to hexadecimal numbers, lets call one of those numbers 0xC4. Finally, you just have to do this:

```
    .whatever { background-color: #C4C4C4; }
```

That's how.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all three values (RGB) are equal, they are gray

Answer (score 1):

If you need X grays within the #000000 (Black) to #ffffff (White) range, you will need to divide 255/(x-1) and use the result as a step value for Reg, Green and Blue. To do this in java:

```
int x = 12;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    int c = (int) Math.round(i*255.0/(x-1));
    System.out.printf("%d. #%02x%02x%02x\n", i, c, c, c);
}
```

Note that you have to multiply i with (255.0/(x-1)) then round it to an integer each time to get the closest gray for each step.

The above produces (which is what you've asked for after your edit):

```
0. #000000
1. #171717
2. #2e2e2e
3. #464646
4. #5d5d5d
5. #747474
6. #8b8b8b
7. #a2a2a2
8. #b9b9b9
9. #d1d1d1
10. #e8e8e8
11. #ffffff
```